# Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch'

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna, monogame

I'm currently developing a 2d space shooter in Monogame. In my game I use Stopwatches to manage delays between events such as the player ship's shot delay and various enemy ship's attacks.

For example, when the user presses space bar I call the following method:

```
if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
{
    if (Logic.PlayerShotDelay.ElapsedMilliseconds > Projectile.shotdelay)
    {
        // Fire player shot code

        Logic.PlayerShotDelay.Restart();
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly, no problems. However I try to use the same technique in another method:

```
if (currentanimation.frame < 13)
{
    if (Logic.FrameDelay.ElapsedMilliseconds > Logic.FrameDelay)
    {
         currentanimation.Draw(spriteBatch);
         currentanimation.frame++;
         Logic.FrameDelay.Restart();
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

Error 1 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch'

Both Projectile.shotdelay and Logic.FrameDelay are static ints. As far as I can see, my if statements are functionally identical. I'm completely confused as to why this isn't working. Upon searching I've got results relating to non nullable ints but I can't apply the solutions to given to my particular problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: `Logic.FrameDelay` can't be a static int - you just treated it as a Stopwatch class instance on the very same line!

Comment: `Logic.FrameDelay` is a stopwatch, it's obviously you can't compare those things in such a way.

Comment: Ugh, thanks very much. I changed a variable name and ended up confusing myself. I didn't see how obvious the error was until it was pointed out to me. How do I mark this question as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the same line you are treating FrameDelay as a class and as a "int"

`Logic.FrameDelay`.ElapsedMilliseconds > `Logic.FrameDelay`